# How do a handle a database with over 100 tables

Tags: database, entity-framework

I have a database with over a 100 tables, 30 of them are lookup tables with lookup Language tables.  each table links back to one or three tables.  but there are around 20 different web forms that needs to interlink for a registered user.

My question is, do i create one connection string with one Model, or do i break them up into individual models?

I've tried the breaking up into individual models based on the page that they are required for, but this just throws up validation and reference errors looking for the same field.

I don't have any errors to show at the moment, but i can provide if necessary.

Comment: Which type of database? Which database system?

Comment: I'm using my sql db 2012. Do I just make a view of all the tables, or do I create separate views for each application?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create some views so that you can consolidate the queries coming from the database. Try to think of logical groupings of the tables (lookup and otherwise) that you have and create a view for each logical grouping. Then, have your application query against those views to retrieve data.

As for connection strings, I don't see why you would need more than one if all of the tables are in the same database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to create only one connection string, that is what you should do.

When you create a second connection string, it's because you have no choice. Having many different connections strings is just going to add to the confusion you migth already be in.

The number of tables you have in a data base is never going to influence how many connection string you should have. I would even say : having acces to all the information of your database through one single object is an advantage. Now, the way you are going to organise the impressive amount of informations is crucial, and there is a lot of way to accomplish that. You need to find out yours.